# Hiding automatically added input (user) button in Safari 10(?)

Tags: css, html, safari, safari10

Any idea how i can hide [this annoying input icon/button in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBPU.png) via CSS? I have no idea what the meaning of this new icon is because for me it has no functionality.

Thx a million, Thomas

Comment: When does this show up?

Comment: Strange is, i found no rule on which input field is shown and which not. Sometimes in date fields (which are not marked as type="date") and sometime other fields like first name, last name etc. After reloading the page it can be that its not shown, only after next reload. Really no clue. I already hide via CSS the calendar picker, inner/outer spinner HTML5/Webkit elements by default, because i have to do it myself for my admin panel. But this not help for this strange new icon/button. https://www.ideaweb.de/s/160926c2osz.png

Comment: Found out its the setting "AutoFill web forms: Using info from my contacts", but any chance to not show it because autocomplete="off" seems not to help?

Answer (score 6):

i resolved this problem this way

```
input:focus::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663578/how-to-hide-autofill-safari-icon-in-input-field

Answer (score 0):

I have notice that icon appears if none empty label before exist.
Possible solution is to remove all text from label and put it as css property using "after", like that:

html

```
<label></label>
<input>
```

css

```
label:before {
content: 'some text for label';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that is seems to be gone in 10.1.1

Comment: I have it in 10.1.2