# Mac safari strange symbol issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css, safari

I have a website which is build with asp.net. There is a text-box which can be used to fill quantity. Sometime a strange icon like a human appear on text box. Attached image below. This strange icon appear only in Mac Safari browser.

[image]

What is it?

Comment: Looks like the auto complete. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663578/how-to-hide-autofill-safari-icon-in-input-field

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no idea, I am unable to reproduce it now :( at my end

Comment: The icon and the arrow appear only when you click on the field.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thank you very much for that stack overflow link. Because I was not able to understand what it means. I was pulling my hair out, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

It is the autofill functionality, indeed. Read more about it on [Apple's support site](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21470?locale=en_US).

The icon and the arrow appear when you click on a field that has a certain HTML name like "name", "password", "email", "phone" etc. The icon depends on the field name. It is a human silhouette for "name", "email" etc but it is a key for "password" and other sensitive information (credit card number, f.e.).

It can use information from external sources (Contacts) and information previously in Safari (passwords, credit card information, regular data filled in web forms).

Each of these sections can be individually enabled/disabled and the data it contains can be edited in the Safari's Preferences.

Comment: In my application, this text-box is for quantity input. Can it be auto-filled  ?

Comment: The browsers usually remember the values the user puts in the fields of type `<input type="text">` in a form and suggest them when the same form is used again. The passwords (`<input type="password">`) have a different handling. If in the past a field was filled with only one value, on subsequent displays some browsers automatically put the value in the field; others suggest previously used values only when the user starts typing in the field. The autofill behaviour is a functionality that the browser producers provide; it is not required by any web standard. You cannot rely on it.

Comment: However, you can put a default value for the field in HTML: `<input type="text" name="quantity" value="42">`. The browser renders the field and puts `42` in it. The user can remove or change the value but if they don't, `42` is the value submitted to the form's action.