# How to hide autofill safari icon in input field in React

Tags: reactjs, safari, icons

In input fields has the little person icon in safari 10 and I search some answers in stackoverflow. Some people suggested used 
[[image: enter image description here]]

but I add it to my project, it shows [[image: enter image description here]]

so there are any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide autofill safari icon in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663578/how-to-hide-autofill-safari-icon-in-input-field)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663578/how-to-hide-autofill-safari-icon-in-input-field) is correct, only your IDE does not have this selector in the database.