# Strange icon on input fields in Safari

Tags: html, input, safari

I have about 10 input fields on a web page. In two of those fields, a strange icon will appear on the field when I put the cursor in those fields, which disappears as soon as I tab or click away. This only happens on Safari, not on Firefox or Chrome.

With cursor:
[image: This is the field with the cursor in it]

Without cursor:
[image: This is the field without the cursor]

I thought it might be LastPass doing it, so I turned off Extensions in the Develop menu.

Here is the exact source for one of the fields:

```
<tr name="cargo" data-seat="cargo_cabin">
                            <td>
                                Cargo Cabin
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right" colspan="2">
                                <input name="cargo_weight" value="" class="text-right"
                                    type="text"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="cargo_arm"
                                    class="form-control-plaintext text-right" readonly
                                    value="357.50"/>
                            </td>
                            <td name="cargo_moment">
                                <input type="text" name="cargo_moment"
                                    class="form-control-plaintext text-right" readonly value=""/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516054/9285506

Comment: @ddr45 I had to change it to `-web-contacts-auto-fill-button` instead of `-web-credentials-auto-fill-button`, but that did the trick.

Comment: So, @ddr45 (and anybody else): Do I delete this, close it as a duplicate, or do I get you to write an answer so I can accept it?