# How to change Safari autofill yellow background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

This image is what I get from safari:

[image: This is what I get from Safari]

While this is my code:

[image: This is from my style sheet]

Sources:

[How to Remove WebKit's Banana-Yellow Autofill Background](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/03/20/how-to-remove-webkits-banana-yellow-autofill-background)

[Remove forced yellow input background in Chrome](http://labs.enonic.com/articles/remove-forced-yellow-input-background-in-chrome) - even it says chrome but still pointing to webkit-autofill

I had tried to use `background-color:white !important;` to override the locked css. Debug tool showed User Agent Stylesheet background-color had crossed out, but still the color didn't change and the custom was in used.

That's what really confused me, I have no idea why aren't allow to change the User Agent Stylesheet.

Comment: Do not think you can override user agent styles especially that are marked  with `!important`

Comment: try addressing the `input` with a class beforehand as well e.g. `input.class { background-color: red !important }`

Comment: @DenisTsoi any reason for addressing the `input` class beforehand?

Comment: I believed specificity would help, however using -webit-box-shadow solves this issue

Comment: depends :(, `opera` and `safari` won't lets you change the **auto-fill**. `firefox`, `ie` and `chrome` are alright.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was reading that most browsers want to indicate autofill (with Safari being a bit more adamant with this indication).

I did find an alternative `hack`, where you use the `-webkit-box-shadow` to cover the background color. Upon inspection, trying to target the specific input with a class doesn't work (i.e. specificity).

In Safari, (10.0.2), the browser adds `shadow content` as the user agent, which includes the background-color and the value of the autofill. The issue here is that, the browser prohibits the the editing of those specific styles (such as `background-color`), therefore the reason for the answer below.

```
input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
```

**if you also have a border-bottom in the input**

```
input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Source:
- [medium-post](https://medium.com/@landonschropp/styling-autocompleted-inputs-in-chrome-and-safari-de83d7bd1d8a#.nqq6nuo5u)
- [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661977/disabling-safari-autofill-on-usernames-and-passwords)
- [why-browsers ignore autocomplete="off"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457066/2903169)

Comment: thanks @Denis, that's really informative. I would turn the autocomplete off if I can, that will save me many hours of digging haha.

Answer (score 27):

What I found out is that those solutions including `-webkit-box-shadow` and `background-color` work only in Google Chrome browser, but not in Safari. What works for me is adding `background-clip: content-box`. In the end, the code (working in all browsers) looks like:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px #fafafa inset !important;
    background-color: #fafafa !important;
    background-clip: content-box !important;
}
```

Comment: This is for me the best answer. Was trying to find a fix for Safari and none of the above answers were working.

This one worked really good for me, thanks for saving me! <3