# Can't stop autocomplete from showing up in Safair

Tags: input, autocomplete, safari

I'm trying to stop the autocomplete pop window from showing in Safari. All other browser work correctly and don't show it, but Safari does.

```
<input autofill="none" autocorrect="off" type="text" name="client[name]" id="client_name" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Also, this field isn't for username or passwords so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with a noted Sarari bug with those types of fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Safari autofill on usernames and passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661977/disabling-safari-autofill-on-usernames-and-passwords)

Comment: Just checking, is it stored in Safari?  They have their own autofill just like google does