# Javascript first click on input with a suggestion doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I am trying to attach a click handler on an input, but for some reason it doesn't work for first click on inputs that get `autosuggestion` in safari. All other clicks after the first one work. So for example if an input has a name or label before it saying `First name`, `Last name`, `Email` or anything similar Safari will put a suggestion widget at the end of the input and suggest my information that is in Keychain Access I guess. Click event will not trigger the first time I click on that input, after the first one it triggers ok.

Here is the code that produces this issue. Basically I need a way to trigger a click event on inputs every time it gets clicked (preferably vanilla js, but jquery would be ok too).

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    // Click on this input doesn't trigger the first time I click it because Safari has a suggestion widget for this input
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" data-input="">

    // Click on this input triggers every time I click it with no issue
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required="" data-input="">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-input]');

var myFunction = function(event) {
    console.log('Clicked');
};

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // I put this console.log here to see if all of the inputs pass through this for loop to get the event listener and they do
    console.log(inputs[i]);
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}
```

EDIT: even though @gopigorantala's link in his comment might be considered duplicate, I am not looking for the same thing that question is looking for. That question asks for a way to disable safari autosuggestion feature on inputs, I am looking for a way to detect clicks on inputs despite autosuggestion being there.

Comment: duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661977/disabling-safari-autofill-on-usernames-and-passwords

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/20yco/s15y6gzp/1/ first click trigger works for me in safari

Comment: @gopigorantala I searched but didn’t come across this answer, thanks for linking! I need a js solution though if possible, without fake input fields as this is intended for js plugin so I wouldn’t like to do anything in the html. 20yco  it works in jsfiddle and codepen for some reason because safari doesn’t try to autofill these inputs.

Comment: @MarioPlantosar tried this in local index.html in Safari browser, all works fine, hm

Comment: @20yco hmmm, maybe safari/keychain access doesn’t have your info to fill inputs so there is no suggestion

Comment: @MarioPlantosar can you try this one in safari? http://jsfiddle.net/20yco/56zwb1kv/6/, works not perfect, but i'm think true is near