# how to disable autofill on mac?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using many example for hide autofill on mac but its not working for me..

```css
<style>
    input::-webkit-autofill
</style>
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />

    <button type="submit"><i class="material-icons send"></i></button>
</div>
```

But it's not working for me

Please suggest me a better example...

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661977/disabling-safari-autofill-on-usernames-and-passwords

Comment: thanks this css works for me `input::-webkit-contacts-auto-fill-button, 
input::-webkit-credentials-auto-fill-button {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}`